# Is there a symbol for contradiction?

Tags: logic

I once heard my teacher say

> This is a contradiction which means this proposition is always false.

about an equality and they added a symbol next to that equation.

It was a cross with exclamation mark next to it. I don't think I have seen that symbol anywhere else.

Is there a symbol for contradictions?

Comment: The TeX page [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358065/how-to-typeset-contradiction-symbol) says $$
\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow
$$ I would use a lightening symbol.

Comment: $\bot$ is also used. Remember that you can do nearly anything with notation, as long as you define it first.

Comment: For what it's worth $\bot$ (`\bot`) has the advantage of pairing nicely with a tautology symbol, $\top$ (`\top`).